# Archetypes in powered mtg-cube

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-cube

What archetypes are most common/popular to include in powered cubes (preferably size 540)?

Answer (score 1):

**Mono-Red**. Aggressive creatures and burn.

**White Weenie**. Aggressive creatures, cheap removal and equipment.

**Mono-Black Aggro**. Aggressive creatures, removal and discard.

**U/W Control**. Counterspells, board wipes, removal, card draw and a few big finishers.

**5-Color Control**. Like U/W but with more powerful spells and mana-fixing.

**Reanimator**. Put fatties in the graveyard and then reanimate them cheaply and quickly. This requires some card draw and filtering to go off reliably. This deck often contains removal and permission like a control deck, too.

**Ramp**. Spend your early turns putting extra lands on the battlefield and playing mana rocks. Then, start dropping fatties before your opponent can.

**Storm Combo**. Draw through your deck quickly, upping your storm count until you finish your opponent with Grapeshot or Empty the Warrens.

**Land Destruction**. Play mana rocks early and then cripple your opponent with a spell like Armageddon or Jokulhaups.